# How does one go about implementing the ContractTransactor interface from the bind package in go-ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation, geth-debugging, golang

**Hey guys thanks in advance!**

Here is the interface provided by the go-ethereum library in the bin package.  I need an example on how to implement this interface please :)

```
// ContractTransactor defines the methods needed to allow operating with contract
// on a write only basis. Beside the transacting method, the remainder are helpers
// used when the user does not provide some needed values, but rather leaves it up
// to the transactor to decide.
type ContractTransactor interface {
    // PendingCodeAt returns the code of the given account in the pending state.
    PendingCodeAt(ctx context.Context, account common.Address) ([]byte, error)
    // PendingNonceAt retrieves the current pending nonce associated with an account.
    PendingNonceAt(ctx context.Context, account common.Address) (uint64, error)
    // SuggestGasPrice retrieves the currently suggested gas price to allow a timely
    // execution of a transaction.
    SuggestGasPrice(ctx context.Context) (*big.Int, error)
    // EstimateGas tries to estimate the gas needed to execute a specific
    // transaction based on the current pending state of the backend blockchain.
    // There is no guarantee that this is the true gas limit requirement as other
    // transactions may be added or removed by miners, but it should provide a basis
    // for setting a reasonable default.
    EstimateGas(ctx context.Context, call ethereum.CallMsg) (gas uint64, err error)
    // SendTransaction injects the transaction into the pending pool for execution.
    SendTransaction(ctx context.Context, tx *types.Transaction) error
}
```

*I have some basic starter code here, so that people can see where I need the interface applied.*

```
package main

import (
    "MyProject/constants"
    "MyProject/contracts"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "math/big"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    contractAddress,err:=common.NewMixedcaseAddressFromString("hexFun")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    userAddress,err:=common.NewMixedcaseAddressFromString("hexFun")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    userMainAddress := userAddress.Address()
    mainConctractAddress := contractAddress.Address()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(abiObj)
    //LOOOOOOOK HERE PEOPLE THANK YOU --------------------------------------

    var one bind.ContractTransactor
    transactor, err:=contracts.NewERC721Transactor(mainConctractAddress,one)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    auth, err := bind.NewTransactor(strings.NewReader(constants.GetEthKey()),constants.GetEthParaphrase())
    trans, err:=transactor.Mint(auth,userMainAddress,big.NewInt(123))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(trans.Hash())

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`ethclient`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/ethclient/ethclient.go) package implements the `ContractTransactor` interface, so you just have to instantiate the client:

```
client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://mainnet.infura.io")
```

and then you can pass it to your contract transactor method:

```
transactor, err:= contracts.NewERC721Transactor(mainContractAddress, client)
```